# Unable to fetch an API from carquery API using fetch()

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from carquery API using a fetch request, however I receive an error

**GET https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?cmd=getModels&make=ford&year=2005&sold_in_us=1&body=SUV net::ERR_FAILED**

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch**

```
const fetchItems = async () =>{
    // const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=5')

    const data = await fetch('https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getModels&make=ford&year=2005&sold_in_us=1&body=SUV')

    const items = await data.json()
    console.log(items)
    setItems(items)
}
```

This is the response I get in postman
[image]

Comment: Is your application running in a different URL domain? It is probably a CORS issue. If the API does not return a header that looks something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` you cannot make AJAX/fetch calls to it from different domains without creating a proxy service in your domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS

Answer (score 1):

In the error you've included, there is a missing ampersand before the `cmd` query parameter (although the code you shared has it, so just check the URL carefully). The error you show above is returned when you don't wrap your code in a `try...catch`. Without the catch, the real details of the error will be obscured.

It seems that the API doesn't return properly formatted JSON as the response, so you can get the items as plain text, trim off the offending characters with `slice` and then parse the string manually.

```js
const fetchItems = async () => {
  const url = 'https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getModels&make=ford&year=2005&sold_in_us=1&body=SUV'
  const headers = {
    headers : { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  try {
    const data = await fetch(url, headers)

    const items = await data.text()

    console.log(JSON.parse(items.slice(2, -2)))
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```